# TypeError: connect() argument 4 must be str, not WindowsPath . /*The Error that i m getting in my simple login django project*/

Tags: django

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
February 17, 2021 - 19:52:27
Django version 3.1.6, using settings 'felix.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
C:\Users\FELIX\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\django login2\felix\felix\settings.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 459, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 216, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FELIX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
TypeError: connect() argument 4 must be str, not WindowsPath
```

Answer (score 3):

I got similar error information while doing makemigrations, and str() worked.

```
# BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': str(BASE_DIR / 'my.cnf')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeError: connect() argument 4 must be str, not WindowsPath, parece referirse a que la línea 4 de la conexión tiene un formato no estándar para el path, solo es revisar el formato de la conexión a DB, por ejemplo:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'project_django_1',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 3306,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are using mysql you do not needed to give the path just creat database and put the name of database

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'your-database-name',
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you set mysql Database setting?
Please check you set DATABASE right.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'mysql username',
        'PASSWORD': 'mysql user password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': 3306,
    }
}
```